# Returning a map object in cypher

Tags: cypher, redisgraph

I need to create edges between a set of nodes but it is not guaranteed that the edge is not exists already, I need to know which edges has been created so I can increment the edges counter for the two connected nodes.

I want to know the edges count for every node without querying the graph each time.

Example:

```
MERGE (u:user {id:999049043279872})
MERGE (g1:group {id:346709075951616})
MERGE (g2:group {id:346709075951617})
MERGE (g1)-[m1:member]->(u)
MERGE (g2)-[m2:member]->(u)
```

Sometimes the user is already a member of the group so I don't want to increment the counter in this case.

I tried to use the result statistics but it returns the created relationships number only, I thought also about using a map and then fill the content using `ON CREATE SET` after `MERGE`:

```
WITH {g1:0, g2:0} as res
MERGE (u:user {id:999049043279872})
MERGE (g1:group {id:346709075951616})
MERGE (g2:group {id:346709075951617})
MERGE (g1)-[m1:member]->(u)
ON CREATE SET res.g1 = 1
MERGE (g2)-[m2:member]->(u)
ON CREATE SET res.g2 = 1
RETURN res
```

But it does not works; the server crashes immediately after executing the query.

Exception:

> ------ FAST MEMORY TEST ------
> 17235:M 28 Feb 2022 16:56:50.016 # main thread terminated
> 17235:M 28 Feb 2022 16:56:50.017 # Bio thread for job type #0 terminated
> 17235:M 28 Feb 2022 16:56:50.017 # Bio thread for job type #1 terminated
> 17235:M 28 Feb 2022 16:56:50.018 # Bio thread for job type #2  terminated
>
> Fast memory test PASSED, however your memory can still be broken.
> Please run a memory test for several hours if possible.
>
> ------ DUMPING CODE AROUND EIP ------
> Symbol: (null) (base: (nil))
> Module: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (base 0x7fbfe3dcc000)
> $ xxd -r -p /tmp/dump.hex /tmp/dump.bin
> $ objdump --adjust-vma=(nil) -D -b binary -m i386:x86-64 /tmp/dump.bin
>
> === REDIS BUG REPORT END. Make sure to include from START to END. ===
>
> Please report the crash by opening an issue on github:
>
> http://github.com/redis/redis/issues
>
> Suspect RAM error? Use redis-server --test-memory to verify it.
>
> Segmentation fault

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm sorry but I miss the point. You said in the first sentence that if the relationships you are going to create already exists, then you need to increment the counter. Then you said that if the user is already a member of the group, you don't have to increment the counter.  So, when do you have to increment the counter?

Comment: Imagine that you have 5 nodes which you need to connect to another node `y` , and you have a counter for node `y` to know how many nodes are connected to it, so the condition should be if (n belongs to nodes) not connected to `y` yet then add edge and increment counter.

Comment: @Rawhi Can you please add a reproducible query (or set of queries) that causes RedisGraph to crash? Also, which version of RedisGraph are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Neo4j stores already a counter inside each node to count the number of relationships and to provide a fast count access. When you want to get the number of members in a group, you can simply do:

```
MATCH (g:group)
return size((g)<-[:member]-())
```

Comment: Yes I know, that is exactly what I'm trying to do in `redisgraph` but manually, since it does not support such feature.